# Wagtail Django group pictures into albums based on their tags

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I was wondering if it's possible to arrange pictures uploaded to wagtail into galleries based on their tags.

I have an album app, and its models.py contains :

```
from django.db import models
from wagtail.wagtailcore.models import Page

# Create your models here.
class Category(Page):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
   slug = models.SlugField()
   image = models.ImageField()
   parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, related_name='children')

   def __str__(self):
       return self.name

class Post(Page):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', null=True, blank=True)
    publish = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, )
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
```

Comment: To clarify - do you want to arrange these pictures on the frontend (eg. in your CategoryPage view ?) or in the Wagtail admin area? Also, when you say tags, do you mean the built in tags on images or via the `category` shown in the model above?

Answer (score 0):

Images use `django-taggit` for its [tags](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/61698981feda84729b562eec5424b90365b15650/wagtail/wagtailimages/models.py#L80) so you can query them easily.

```
from wagtail.wagtailimages import get_image_model


# Somewhere in your code
image_class = get_image_model()
images = image_class.objects.filter(tags__name='the_slug')
```

---

On a side note, the `slug` field on your `Category` page in your snippet might shadow the `slug` field of the base `Page` model so you might want to be careful with that.